# c# textbox search with hints

Tags: c#, list, blazor

I want to do a search with hints on blazor.

I have

```
<input @oninput="Search" placeholder="Search Text" class="p-3" />

@if (ShortList is null || !ShortList.Any())
{
    <p><em>Empty</em></p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var l in ShortList)
    {
         <p>@l.Id @l.FullName</p>
    }
}

private List<long> SearchList { get; set; }  //get List Id from search text


@code
{
    private async void Search(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var searchTerm = (string)args.Value;
        SearchList = await _db.SearchByName(searchTerm);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Next, I want to use this list to get data for each ID from the database and do some actions and add it to a new list

```
private List<ShortList> ResultList = new List<ShortList>();
```

When can I do this for what event?

I tried

```
   foreech (long id in SearchList)
    {
      here is my code
    }
```

Also I tried calling the method here

```
private async void Search(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var searchTerm = (string)args.Value;
    SearchList = await _db.SearchByName(searchTerm);
    StateHasChanged();
    GetShortList();

}
```

But this doesn't work because the SearchList is very large. And it does not match the entered text. I need something like an event when rows are added to the list.

Comment: What flavor of Blazor is it?  I'm assuming server?

Comment: How many possible search terms are there?  YOu don't want to keep accessing your database.  You should have a Singleton service that holds all your search terms, and also returns matching items.  You should call your DB only once.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you assign a new instance of a filtered list, it will trigger a re-render.

This structure below works as long as the `SearchByName` method returns data.

`razor html`

```html
<input @oninput="Search" placeholder="Search Text" />

@if (Matches == null || Matches.Count == 0)
{
    <p><em>Empty</em></p>
}
else
{
    foreach (var match in Matches)
    {
         <p>@match</p>
    }
}
```

`razor code`

```
@code
{
    private IReadOnlyCollection<string> Matches {get; set;}

    private async Task Search(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var searchTerm = (string)args.Value;
        Matches = await SearchByNameAsync(searchTerm);
    }

    private async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> SearchByNameAsync(string searchTerm)
    {
        // TODO: fetch from database
    }
}
```

Working example with data loaded from a remote API:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/ayc3im3m

Comment: This does not work. There are 10k+ lines in the list. And according to this indicator, the result of GetShortList(); And at this time I added another letter and the SearchList was updated and became smaller. currently all results of GetShortList(); according to the old list.

Comment: You need to be more specific about why it "does not work", and state your requirements more clearly. For example, you could have a virtualised dropdown that doesn't fill the DOM with unused elements. You could use debouncing to reduce the number of searches you are making. 10K+ lines is only difficult because you are only viewing your problem in one way rather than breaking your problem down into fundamentals and considering alternatives.

Comment: I'll explain. If you enter one letter in the search field, a Task Search is performed. While it is running, I have already pressed the second button on the keyboard and there are already two letters in the text field - I need a new updated list. But I'm still searching for one letter. Explained as best I could. 
I solved this problem by limiting the number of characters to search. But there is another problem. If I type very quickly TaskSearch does not have time to work correctly, I try Thread.Sleep(500); This kind of helps, but I don't like this delay.

Comment: That's a problem that debouncing would solve.

Comment: Just to expand on that - that's why I think it is important to break the problem down into fundamentals. Think about each keypress in isolation. You start with an empty input. One key is pressed. What problems do you face at this point? Is the database query slow? Is it difficult to render the list? Why do these problems magically vanish when the search term is > 2?

Comment: The other problem is when the next letter is typed before the list for the first letter is rendered. Do you want to wait a short time before sending requests? Do you want to cancel any "in-flight" requests? What are the fundamental problems you are facing? There are lots of questions to ask just in this basic example

Comment: The truth is you may want to use a combination of strategies, but each strategy in itself is a piece of research.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn’t use oninput but something else like onkeyap, but for some reason onkeyup doesn’t compile.

Comment: There wouldn't be a significant difference between the two. The only significant difference would be between oninput/keyup/keydown/etc and onchange. If you want to cancel active requests you will need to look into the use of cancellation tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Search length limitation.

```
if (searchTerm.Length > 2)
    {
        SearchList = await _db.SearchByName(searchTerm);
        StateHasChanged();
        GetShortList();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a general solution to the problem - it is one way of solving your particular scenario. How does it scale? Does it fundamentally solve your problem, or does it just move the problem around?